# How to capture a REST API gateway path parameter from Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

**Justification for asking here** : I have trying to make this very simple thing work for days, even though POST API consuming only the payload worked within minutes. Amazon's own documentation is outdated, and many tutorials on Youtube are showing options that are different from AWS UI now. I also tried looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72425059/how-to-query-parameters-with-api-gateway-to-lambda), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57014913/unable-to-process-path-parameter-in-api-gateway-lambda), but they need either something more complicated, or the answer is outdated.

**Problem** : I have the simple use case of needing to create an API

```
GET URL/{id}
```

Backed by a python lambda function. But the lambda function is not getting the path parameters.

**How do I know it is not working** :
In my python lambda function, I dump the event json, and it comes as empty {}

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    current_time = datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    table.put_item(
        Item={
            "timevalue": current_time,
            "eventvalue": json.dumps(event)
        }
```

**What I tried, as per AWS documentation** :

1. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-custom-integrations.html

This does not specify how to get the ARN of the function-invoking action, nor how to set it up. That is the main point of the whole document, which is missing. Without it, I get no event gets passed to my function.

2. Following https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-lambda-http-endpoint, I do not get passed any parameter in event, when invoked like

   'GET URL/{id}'.

Although, it must be noted that this "knowledge center" is highly outdated, and a lot of guesswork is required to follow it. There is no "Actions" to click before "Create Resource". There is no "New Child Resource" pane, and if I choose "Create Resource" instead of it, then there is no "Configure as proxy resource".

Answer (score 1):

With regard to variant 2 (https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/api-gateway-lambda-http-endpoint).

Have you already checked the possible parameters for the mapping template here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-mapping-template-reference.html ? There is a variable $context.path. You should be able to use this to map the path into the input parameters for the lambda.

Comment: I was able to make it work by precisely using the mapping templates, but the wrong / outdated documentation set me back a few days.